# Incorporating Twitter Feed into Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, php, twitter, rss

I'm in Visual Studio 2013 and I'm looking to incorporate Design Chemical's Social Stream Blocks (a group of different social network's rss feeds) into our website. We're using Web Forms within VS and since twitter needs an authorization to post it's feed, we've used Design Chemical's provided twitter.php document with the appropriate Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Token, Access Token secret, etc into our VS environment. VS doesn't run php by default, and we're trying to get around installing the PHP Tools extension for VS. Money is not the problem, we're just trying to keep our environment clean and universal for all our developers. Every other social network feed is working - just not twitter's. Suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are existing libraries that you can use or examine their code. Here's a list from the Twitter developer site:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries